# SQLCipher + POCO C++

Tags: sqlite, build, sqlcipher, poco-libraries

I'm trying to replace POCO's sqlite with [sqlcipher](http://sqlcipher.net/) on my Mac Lion. There's not a lot of info around in regards to the build process and replacement, however I figured I should give it a try.

I've got the sqlcipher amalgamation, then I've replaced sqlite3.c and sqlite3.h in the Data/Sqlite/src Poco directory with those of sqlcipher, added the SQLITE_HAS_CODEC and SQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 params to the Makefile and tried to build this whole thing.

However I'm getting the following errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_EVP_get_cipherbyname", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_activate in sqlite3.o
      _sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_cipher in sqlite3.o
  "_OPENSSL_add_all_algorithms_noconf", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_activate in sqlite3.o
  "_RAND_bytes", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_random in sqlite3.o
  "_EVP_CIPHER_key_length", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_cipher in sqlite3.o
  "_EVP_CIPHER_iv_length", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_cipher in sqlite3.o
  "_EVP_CIPHER_block_size", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_cipher in sqlite3.o
  "_EVP_sha1", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_cipher in sqlite3.o
      _sqlcipher_page_hmac in sqlite3.o
  "_EVP_MD_size", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_codec_ctx_set_cipher in sqlite3.o
  "_HMAC_CTX_init", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_page_hmac in sqlite3.o
  "_HMAC_Init_ex", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_page_hmac in sqlite3.o
  "_HMAC_Update", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_page_hmac in sqlite3.o
  "_HMAC_Final", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_page_hmac in sqlite3.o
  "_HMAC_CTX_cleanup", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_page_hmac in sqlite3.o
  "_EVP_CipherInit", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_page_cipher in sqlite3.o
  "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_set_padding", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_page_cipher in sqlite3.o
  "_EVP_CipherUpdate", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_page_cipher in sqlite3.o
  "_EVP_CipherFinal", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_page_cipher in sqlite3.o
  "_EVP_CIPHER_CTX_cleanup", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_page_cipher in sqlite3.o
  "_PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC_SHA1", referenced from:
      _sqlcipher_cipher_ctx_key_derive in sqlite3.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

Has anybody tried this before? Does anybody know a potential fix for this? Thanks!

Comment: hi, can you share what source code in poco/sqlite/src should be relaced by ciphter?thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those are OpenSSL symbols, so you are probably not linking against libcrypto. Add `-lcrypto` to the linker flags.

Comment: Yep that did the trick! I was linking incorrectly. Thanks a lot for the help!